# Declaring global variable inside jquery .get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, get

Cannot declare global variable inside this jquery method. What I am missing and how to do it?

```js
var info = "empty";
 
$.get("http://ip-api.com/json", function(response) {
  info = response.city;
 }, "jsonp");
 
 console.log(info);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$.get` is async method so your `console.log` will show initial value.Put `console.log` inside `$.get` and you will see updated value,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the variable like

```
var info = "";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://ip-api.com/json", function(response) {
        info = response.city;
        console.log(info);
    }, "jsonp");
});
```